# Fixed position with multiple floats

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

Good day everyone,

I'm having a bit of a problem, I know I've done this before but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how I did it.

I have a website that uses 3 columns.

Left, Content, and Right.

The Left and Right columns I wish to remain on screen during scrolling. I have accomplished this using Jquery and CSS fixed positioning.

```
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.paddingTop{
    padding-top:110px;
}
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(window).scroll(function () {
                            t = $('#contentliquid').offset();
                            t = t.top;

                            s = $(window).scrollTop();

                            d = t - s;

                            if (d < 0) {
                                $('#leftcolumnwrap').addClass('fixed');
                                $('#leftcolumnwrap').addClass('paddingTop');
                            } else {
                                $('#leftcolumnwrap').removeClass('fixed');
                                $('#leftcolumnwrap').removeClass('paddingTop');
                            }
                        });
            </script>
```

The problem is that each object is set to float. The reason it is set to float is because the website has to be adjustable to multiple environments and sizes and setting a top/right/left/bottom with exact pixel values removes the ability to scale the website.

So my Question is this:

How do I keep the Left and Right Columns in position while using floats.

EDIT:

Since everyone was asking for it, here's a jsfiddle. It will only display useless data and give you an idea of the scrolling issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/qq4meudh/1/

Comment: Share your code on http://jsfiddle.net/
Interactive way to run your code..

Comment: I hope you all realize that the issue isn't in the jquery...
posting this on jsfiddle will do nothing as jsfiddle can't process the asp.net code associated with this site.

Comment: can you explain bit more or if you have any visual or example to show.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qq4meudh/1/

Comment: @PRAH It's pretty simple.

3 columns, 2 columns move to immediate left of screen and stack behind one another when the FIX is set, move back into proper position after FIX is removed from CSS.

I need it to remain in the exact location indefinitely but it can't use set pixel values because it needs to scale.

Comment: You can calculate % and use % based on your layout

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your fixed div inside a float div.

CSS

```
#page-wrap { width: 100%; }
#page-wrap > div { margin: 0 0 50px 0; width: 100%; }

.group:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.group { display: inline-block; }

#content {
            position: relative; 
            background: #eee; 
            z-index: 1; 
            width: 100%; 
        }
        #content .col { 
            position: relative; 
            width: 27%; 
            padding: 3%; 
            float: left; 
        }
        #content .col:nth-child(1) { left: 33%; }
        #content .col:nth-child(2) { left: -33.3%; }
        #content .col:nth-child(3) { left: 0; }
        #content:before, #nicolas-gallagher:after {
           content: "";
           position: absolute;
           z-index: -1;
           top: 0;
           left: 33.4%;
           width: 33.4%;
           height: 100%;
           background: #ccc;
        }
        #content:after {
           left: 66.667%;
           background: #eee;
        }

.fix {
    position:fixed;
    width: 27%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="content" class="group">
            <div class="col"><h3>Content</h3><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam convallis auctor suscipit. Integer pellentesque urna et magna convallis, eu ullamcorper orci sagittis. Sed laoreet elementum lectus eu convallis. Praesent fringilla pharetra mollis. Vestibulum eget aliquet leo. Pellentesque molestie diam non molestie pellentesque. Nam finibus est tristique bibendum accumsan. Etiam in felis orci. Vivamus mauris metus, iaculis eu nunc eu, condimentum ullamcorper est.</p></div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="fix">
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="fix">
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**Is this what you want?** https://jsfiddle.net/arglab/xo00533o/2/

Comment: Nope, that'd work if I wasn't using jquery to add/remove a class.